# Weird border in boodstrap menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a navabar with bootstrap 3. But the problem is that a weird border appears in my menu and the menu items don't take the full height of the navbar.

This is the code:

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="www.site.com">
                <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="site.com"/>

            </a>
            <div class="navbar navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                </ul> <!-- end nav-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><strong class="caret"></strong> Select language</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a href="">NL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">IL</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">ENG</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul> <!-- end nav menu right -->
            </div> <!-- end nav-collapse -->

        </div> <!-- end container -->
    </div> <!-- end navbar -->
```

I have added a sample over here: http://jsfiddle.net/yn9C6/

Where does this line come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following styles in your CSS. It will override the default bootstrap style so that you won't get extra padding and unnecessary border.

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form
 {
  border-color:transparent !important;
 }
.navbar
{
  margin-bottom:0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a css class to override those.

```
.test{
    border-color:transparent;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

And add the class on div and ul.